# how to get taxonomy children id in drupal

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I have a taxonomy parent tid '8'

I need to get all child tid for this parent id

```
$tid = 8;

$children = taxonomy_get_children($tid);

print_r($children);
```

am getting this result

```
8

Array
(
[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 9
        [vid] => 3
        [name] => Domestic 
        [description] => Domestic 
        [weight] => 0
    )

[12] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 12
        [vid] => 3
        [name] => Economic 
        [description] => Economic 
        [weight] => 1
    )

[11] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 11
        [vid] => 3
        [name] => International
        [description] => 
        [weight] => 2
    )

[10] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 10
        [vid] => 3
        [name] => Social 
        [description] => 
        [weight] => 3
    )

 )
```

how can I display only tid from this array.

Answer (score 4):

```
$children = array_keys(taxonomy_get_children($tid));
```

You will notice it's an associative array where the tid in the object is the same as the array key - just grab the keys, it's equivalent to grabbing the tids from the objects themselves.